# How do I find where Python's libpython is located?

Tags: python, macos, dylib

I'm using Conda on macOS, and I'm getting an error while building a Rust package that it can't find the `libpython3.7m.dylib` library. How can I find this?

After doing some research, on Linux you usually can install it from `python-dev` on Ubuntu, or by enabling --enabled-shared during Python compilation.

Answer (score 5):

Python's build configuration can be found using `distutils.sys_config`.

```py
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var

print(get_config_var("LIBDIR"))
# /Users/liamz/anaconda3/lib

print(get_config_var("LDLIBRARY"))
# libpython3.7m.dylib
```

Or as a one-liner:

`python3 -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var; print(get_config_var("LIBDIR"))'`